# Dynamically change Blazor EditContext at runtime

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am struggled at some point of my Blazor Server App validation.

There is a context Model "Order". During the CRUD operations there can be a new customer added or select an existing customer.

There is a first InputSelect with options New or Existing. According to it there is a hide/show logic where to display a inputtext for a new customer, so the user can enter a customer name or display an inputselect, so user can chose an existing customer.

That logic is working fine over there.

The problem is: when user choses New customer and enter customer name, I would like to remove the CustomerId model field from current EditContext. It means if a new customer is being entered, there is no need to validate an existing customer.

However I didn't find any method or collection to manipulate EditContext field's collection after it is created.

So, please, if anyone has some solution, I appreciate.

```
private class Order
{

    [StringLength(maximumLength: 200, MinimumLength = 3,ErrorMessage ="Enter the customer name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Enter the customer name") ]
    [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; } = "";

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please select the option")]
    [Display(Name = "Existing Customer")]
    public Int16 ExistingCustomerId { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please select the customer")]
    [Display(Name = "Customer")]
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `EditContext` can deal with this. You can change the context. Just [capture the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#capture-references-to-components) for `EditContext` (`<EditContext @ref="myEditContext" ...`) and set the new context.

Comment: It is almost that I need. Actually I didn't want to change to a new context, otherwise I would need to have 2 contexts which the only difference would be one field. I actually wanted to use existing context but just remove some field attribute from it manually. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment I understand that you don't want to have two models, but this would be the simplest way, they can inherit from each other

```
public class AddModel {
    // all fields except ID here
}

public class EditModel : AddModel {
    // just add id property here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark Milford. I will follow this approach